# Running 'drive init' with subprocess

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to make a Python GUI that includes a button for connecting Google Drive to the Raspberry Pi. This process is pretty simple with the terminal - I just have to type `drive init`, copy and paste the URL, follow instructions on the browser, and copy and paste the authentication code back into terminal.

I think if I can get the URL from the `drive init` command, I should be good to go. But I am having the hardest time, for some reason, getting this information.

So far, I've tried using this:

```
p=subprocess.Popen(['drive','init'],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

stdout,stderr=p.communicate()

print(stdout,stderr)
```

and the result I get is:

```
b'' b'init: 1: init: drive: not found\n'
```

My suspicion is that stdout is only printing the last line, which asks for the authentication code. I would really appreciate any help on getting the URL from this process!

Comment: `b'' b'init: 1: init: drive: not found\n'` looks like the result of missing environment variables. Try replacing your subprocess code with `cmd_output = subprocess.check_output(["/full/path/to/drive_executable", "init"])`. If you don't know where `drive` is located, type `which drive` in terminal and copy/paste the full path into python.

Comment: The `shell=True` is superfluous, if not the source of your trouble.

Comment: I still had to use subprocess.Popen because the return value was non-zero and kept giving errors, but the 'which drive' and 'full/path/to/drive' was SO helpful. I solved my problem. Thank you!!!